# AMD64 compiler optimizations with register manipulations

Tags: disassembly, amd64

AMD64 (aka x86-64 or x64) registers can be accessed 8, 16, 32 or 64 bits at a time. When reading a disassembly listing, what register operations are not straightforward?

For example, when an instruction accesses part of a register, how does it affect other parts?

What typical instructions or sequences of instructions used by optimizers might encode something that isn't obvious (e.g. xoring a register with itself to set it to zero)?

Comment: This question is far too broad. It will lead to a list of anecdotes rather than full answers. It should be far more focused, at the very least restricted to a particular topic and preferably to a particular compiler or platform (e.g. stack manipulations in Visual C++). Because there has already been [one answer](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111), I've proposed an edit that focuses on that answer's topic: register manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Gilles. I knew the question was too broad when I asked it but I couldn't rephrase it in a way that still communicated what I wanted.

Comment: I hope the question still approaches what you're interested it. I do encourage you to ask a separate question about stack manipulations with VC++, I'd have edited this question to focus on that but I thought it would me more useful to accommodate the existing answer.

Answer (score 11):

Not really an optimization, but one gotcha that you must be aware of when coming from x86 is this:

#### Any operation on a 32-bit register zeroes out the top half of the 64-bit one

For example, the following:

```
mov eax, 3
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
mov rax, 3
```

This also applies to the new registers `r8`-`r15`, e.g.:

```
inc r8d
```

also zeroes out the top half of `r8`.

*However*, the 8-bit and 16-bit portions of registers do not work like that, i.e. operations on them modify only that part of the register.